# Запрос и ошибка с only_full_group_by

Tags: mysql

Подскажите где у меня ошибка? Переключил версию мускула с 5.6 на 5.7 и появилась ошибка

```
SELECT 
    id, COUNT(*)
FROM
    poi
Error Code: 1140. In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'shelter.poi.id'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

Делаю групировку и он перестает правильно подсчитывать количество

```
SELECT 
    id, COUNT(*)
FROM
    poi
GROUP BY id
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А зачем вы выводите колонку ID, какое значение вы хотите получить в ней, когда считаете количество строк ? без only_full_group_by там было бы первое попавшеея значение, которое никакого смысла не несет

Comment: Если отключить only_full_group_by и убрать GROUP BY id, то выводит как и положено количество строк(равняется 7). Я бы хотел узнать, что я делаю в запросе не так, касательно этой ошибки, т.к. only_full_group_by в версии 5.7 включен по умолчанию и тупо сделать SET sql_mode=''; не очень хороший вариант для меня в данном случае...

Comment: Это count() выдает количество строк. но у вас написано `select id, count(*)` я спрашиваю зачем там колонка id ? Если ее убрать - то запрос разумеется выполнится

Comment: Всё, я понял уже в чём была ошибка=)

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, правильно или нет так делать, но такой запрос работает

```
SELECT id, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM poi)
FROM poi
```

Comment: вам что ли нужны были все записи и рядом с каждой из них общее количество

Comment: Ага, нужны были. Есть еще лучший вариант как их выводить?

Comment: Есть конечно, но он громоздкий. А при текущем варианте вполне возможно что оптимизатор пересчитывает количество при выводе каждой записи. я бы отдельными запросами сделал бы скорее всего